# Set XML file as wallpaper?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-wallpaper

I have xml shape file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#420012"
    android:centerColor="#670000"
    android:endColor="#420012"
    android:type="linear" />
<stroke
    android:width="1px"
    android:color="#560000" />
</shape>
```

How to set it as wallpaper? Is it possible? I need an explanation.

If I execute this, device's default wallpaper to be set.

```
WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.SetResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have included the below permission in your Manifest file:-

```
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
```

And the xml file (bg.xml) that you have created needs to be placed in `drawable` folder under `res` folder which you can set as your wallpaper as per your code:-

```
WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wm.setResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

Comment: Already i mentioned **If I execute this, device's default wallpaper to be set.**

Answer (score 0):

Live wallpaper do drawing using [Surface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html) and [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) APIs. What you can do is inflating some Views from XML and draw() them to a Canvas. But its troublesome. Lengthy and not suggested.